# How to edit data in search result in c#

Tags: c#, database, search, datagridview, edit

I managed to create a code for my edit button and search button. My edit button is functional. It can edit my data in database, my search code is also functional. My problem is to edit data in search results. Like if i search "naruto", my datagridview will filter all the names that has "naruto" on the database. After i choose and doubleclick on the result, all data will reappear to my textbox. But when i edit that data, it doesn't work. Instead, the first data on my database is the one that is changing not the one that i choose. My edit code is working if i don't search any names and don't choose on the search result.

here's my codes. Please HELP...

```
private void JOGridView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from JobOrder", con);

        if (JOGridView.CurrentCell != null && JOGridView.CurrentCell.Value != null)
        {
            TBName.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            TBContact.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            CBStatus.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            TBModel.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            TBSerial.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            TBAccess.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            TBRB.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            TBRP.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            TBIT.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            CBRamarks.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
            TBCharge.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
            TBRELB.Text = JOGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[13].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

 private void BTNEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            DialogResult dr;
            dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Edit this record?", "Update Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM JobOrder", con);
                da.Fill(dt);

                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index].BeginEdit();


                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][1] = TBName.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][2] = TBContact.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][3] = CBStatus.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][4] = TBModel.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][5] = TBSerial.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][6] = TBAccess.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][7] = TBRB.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][8] = DTDR.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][9] = TBRP.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][10] = DTDF.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][11] = TBIT.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][12] = CBRamarks.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][13] = TBCharge.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][14] = TBRELB.Text;
                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][15] = DTDR.Text;

                dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index].EndEdit();

                SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(dt);


                displayrecords();

                MessageBox.Show("Selected record has been Updated!", "Done Updating ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            clearrecords();
        }
    }

    private void TBSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TBSearch.Text == " ")
        {

        }
        else
            con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from JobOrder where Name  like ('" + TBSearch.Text + "%')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        JOGridView.DataSource = dt;

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: are you editing a row in the same page? Do not cram all your codes in one page. Apply separation of concerns. When you hit Search, it will filter those records with "naruto", then when you click the record that you want to update, get the ID (primary key) of that record and bring it to another page to be edited. that way, it will be easier for you to pin poiint what went wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by the same page? Like the same table? If it is table that you are referring for, then yes. what is that separation of concerns? Do you have any sample there that might help to solve my problem?

Comment: I mean, when you hit you are in edit mode, are you doing it on the same window or are you loading another window to edit the record? separation of concerns means, I have a separate page/window for Adding a record, then another separate page/window for editing, then another for deleting and another for searching the list (the window with the datagridview) . that way, I am not cramming all of the codes in one windows form/page, makes it easier to analyze and debug

Comment: load it in the same window. my save, delete and edit are all the same window and only one datagridview.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be more specific without seeing more of your code, but the core problem is at least in part that you're not using an MVVM (model view viewmodel) or MVC style binding between the query results and the database query.

Here's why you're only updating the first row in the table rather than the selected row

```
//creates a new table not visible or linked anywhere
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//gets every record in JobOrder
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM JobOrder", con);
//fills the DataTable dt with all records from JobOrder
da.Fill(dt);

//uses the current index from the items in JOGridView to select a row in the unconnected/unrelated DataTable dt 
dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index].BeginEdit();
dt.Rows[JOGridView.CurrentRow.Index][1] = TBName.Text;
```

If you want it to work as written, you'll need to use some *value* from JOGridView.CurrentRow and match it to a row in dt. Then you can build your update query aimed at the correct row.

Ideally instead, you'll re-write the application to use a proper MVVM style binding to do all of the connections for you automatically.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that MVVM. Maybe i think i just need to change the CurrentRow.Index ... Just guessing because when i edit some data in search result, the 1st data in my database is the one that is changing not the one that i selected from the search result.

Comment: MVVM is the correct way to code something like this because it makes everything faster and easier to code. You should find a tutorial on it and learn it.

Comment: My answer explains why you're not updating the row you want to update in your database. The "CurrentRow.Index" of you JOGridView will never be the row you want in your database because the rows in your view and your query aren't connected. There's nothing in your code that matches the row indices in your view to the rows in your database.